# How to execute a bat file from cygwin bash that uses the Windows find command

Tags: batch-file, cygwin

The `find` command does completely different in Windows and Unix. On Windows it is a `fgrep`-like utility listing matching lines in a file; on Unix -- and on Cygwin -- it list filenames matching some criteria.

Cygwin bash *prepends* its standard directories to the current path, so inside bash `$PATH` is typically `/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS`.

*Begin Update to provide additional details*

For example I have many scripts that use the gnu `find` command -- for example scripts to purge directory trees that contain no files:

```
purge-empty-dirs.sh
find . -depth -type d -empty | xargs rmdir -p
```

I also have a bat file to start my build, which uses the windows find command, which searches for lines matching a string (similar to gnu `grep`).

```
build.bat
...
dir | find "target"
if errorlevel = 1 goto no_target_dir
...
```

Now, for my bash script to work I need `/bin` to be in path before `c:\windows\system32`. But for my bat file to run I need `c:\windows\system32` to be in path before `/bin`

In general we might be able to claim that **all bat files should be executed with the original environment inherited by bash, not the modified one**. Does that make sense?

*End Update*

This how it should be, but breaks the bat files executed from bash. What is the best way to address this?

Is there a way to force Cygwin to execute bat files (or even *all* Windows executables) with the environment it started with? I am thinking of `start /i` behavior of cmd.exe. I am thinking of writing my own `cygstart` like utility that does this, by saving the environment (or at least `$PATH`) in `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc`. Does that make sense?

Any other suggestions?

Edit: See also [Start new cmd.exe and NOT inherit environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261156/start-new-cmd-exe-and-not-inherit-environment/8282423#8282423)

Answer (score 48):

If you `chmod +x your.bat` it works.

```
./your.bat
```

is run via `cmd /c`

Already answered in [Why is it that Cygwin can run .bat scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787522)

Comment: I suspect you don't understand the point of my question, which is that I need to execute the bat file in the original environment, which has since been changed

Comment: Yes, you are right.
Generally this cannot work since `/bin` needs to override `/cygdrive/c/Windows/Systems32`. 
You can only write a bat launcher which strips the cygwin paths before executing `cmd /c bat`. But then you loose. It would be much better to rewrite your bat files with a shell script. bat files are horrible to read and maintain.

Comment: In a perfect world I would be able to rewrite bat files to shell scripts. But I don't live in a perfect world. See my comment [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582778/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-from-cygwin-bash-that-uses-the-windows-find-command/17635020?noredirect=1#comment25661394_17583650)

Comment: can the above method pipe the `.bat` output to a text file from bash?

Comment: Guess most of us only needed to write `./x.bat` :)

Answer (score 7):

I've tested a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282423/2288008) and it works nicely:

```
start "clean shell" /i "%windir%\explorer.exe" "\path\to\your\script.bat"
```

#### Example

`to-run.bat` script:

```
echo %PATH%
echo "TODO: some commands"
cmd
```

`cygwin` bash script, `run-me.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
set -x

SCRIPT_WINPATH=`cygpath --windows --absolute "$1"`
EXPLORER_CYGPATH=`which explorer`
EXPLORER_WINPATH=`cygpath --windows --absolute "${EXPLORER_CYGPATH}"`

cmd /C start "clean shell" /I "${EXPLORER_WINPATH}" "${SCRIPT_WINPATH}"
```

test:

```
chmod +x to-run.bat
chmod +x run-me.sh
./run-me.sh to-run.bat
```

Comment: Thank you. The other question also discusses the same question of starting a process that does not inherit the current environment

Comment: There is already a `/bin/run` on cygwin so `run.sh` may not be the best name.

Comment: All this does is pop up a folder explorer window for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a wrapper, say, `launcher.bat`, whose contents is

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem modify here based on your needs
set PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
call %*
endlocal
exit %errorlevel%
```

Say you want to call `cmdFUBAR.bat` with arg `wellDoneMS` from a cygwin bash script, instead of just `cmdFUBAR.bat wellDoneMS`, you do `cygstart -w launcher.bat cmdFUBAR.bar wellDoneMS`. Of course you have to put `launcher.bat` into your path, or call it with full path.

Answer (score 2):

=== In the build.bat script...

```
SET "DOS_FIND_EXE=%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\find.exe"
...
dir | "%DOS_FIND_EXE%" "target"
if errorlevel 1 goto no_target_dir
...
```

Comment: This works for `find.exe` but not for the general problem of all bat files.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @ruslo is very useful and works just fine, but there a redundancy in it: the `start "clean shell" /I` does nothing here :-) It is the `explorer` piece that gets rid of the current cygwin env, not `start /i`! Try omitting it from the last line of the script, like so:

```
cmd /C "${EXPLORER_WINPATH}" "${SCRIPT_WINPATH}"
```

Same result - "pristine path"!

Perusing the help for `start`, it says: *The new environment will be the original environment passed to the cmd.exe and not the current environment.* Well, but the environment passed to `cmd` in this case is that of `cygwin`, so `start /i` will do nothing useful here, as one can see by typing:

```
cmd /c start /i cmd /c "path && pause"
```

The path is still that of `cygwin`, not the windows system!